# Globally Tag EF Core Queries with ".TagWithCallSite()"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

With the release of the `.TagWithCallSite()` method in EF Core 6.0 I was wondering if there is a way to apply this globally on every query run via a `DbContext` in some way?

It would be much better to apply this across the whole project without having to put it on each query individually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`TagWithCallSite`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/f5f4d62b087525211f65254c3787233175185a30/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2752) accepts parameters marked with [`CallerFilePathAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=net-6.0) and [`CallerLineNumberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute?view=net-6.0) which are filled in by compiler (or manually if needed) during build so it is impossible to set up globally.

Comment: >> it is impossible to set up globally
Using Reflection inside of **DbCommandInterceptor** is possible

Comment: @YuriAbele yes, of course. What will reflection achieve there? In theory you can generate and analyze stack trace but this will significantly impact the performance and still will not be able to repro the behavior in all cases.

Comment: You can add own IQueriable Type Extension-Method with two hidden Parameters:
`[CallerFilePath] string? filePath = null,`
`[CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0`
this is exactly what TagWithCallsite does

Comment: @YuriAbele add to where? Add when?

Comment: neee ...... Without Reflection it will be impossible :-/

Comment: @YuriAbele can you please post a gist on github with the implementation. I would be very glad to see the approach.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cant't do that.

When you explicitly define `TagWithCallSite()`, complier automatically fills default parameters `filePath` and `lineNumber`. It is not possible to define that for all queries because compiler do not store such information in Expression Tree.