# How to know which LINQ statement produced the SQL at runtime Or Is there a way to inject a unique string into every Linq statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm writing an ASP.NET application that uses EntityFramework 6.4.4 version. I'm having trouble debugging a Linq statement that's causing an error. I want to be able to see the C# Method that was generated Linq statement, but I don't know which method produced which LINQ statement.

I have copied the extension method from Stack Overflow for your reference.

Code Samples:

```
public List<EmployeeClone> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        var context = new TryDbContext();
        List<Employee> employees = context.Employees.SetQueryName().ToList();
        
        return employees;
    }

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<T> SetQueryName<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
      [CallerMemberName] String name = null,
      [CallerFilePath] String sourceFilePath = "",
      [CallerLineNumber] Int32 sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        var expr = Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Constant("Query name: " + name), Expression.Constant(null));
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "param");
        var criteria1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>(expr, param);

        expr = Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Constant($"Source: {sourceFilePath} ({sourceLineNumber})"), Expression.Constant(null));
        var criteria2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>(expr, param);
        Console.WriteLine($"{criteria1.Body} && {criteria2.Body}");
        return source.Where(criteria1).Where(criteria2);
    }
}
```

Basically I want to execute this extension method all time whenever i called  context.Employees entity or all entity which is been used in my current dbcontext. This will help me which method generate wearied LINQ statement at SQL server and then appropriate action will taken on that method. I want to call that extension method whenever context.Entity requested.

```
List<Employee> employees = context.Employees.SetQueryName().ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried adding query tags? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tags

Comment: You can't do that automatically. You have to call this method (if it works for sure) for ALL places explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I want to do exactly the same thing, but my application is very large and it has thousands of entities that are firing database queries. I want to inject a piece of code before they are called. I can't make change to all entity but I want to investigate cause by adding in Context class or some overriding entity method.

Comment: `SetQueryName` builds expression tree based on caller function name. This information injected by compiler. No idea how it can be done for all queries,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging

Comment: I used factory logging in console to investigate but my main problem is don't know which method generate the wired satement.

Comment: you can use a global query interceptor and a tag to your query before executing it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partial solution to my problem, but my original question still remains open. I am trying to override the `TagWithCallSite` method to all entities. I have found a way to do this for a specific entity type, but I am not sure how to do it for all entity types. it also logged in sql server profiler.
[image]

Here is the code that I have for overriding the `TagWithCallSite`  method for a specific entity type:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new TryDbContext();

        var employees = context.Employees.TagWithCallSite().ToList();

        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(employee.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found stack overflow post about my problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658204/globally-tag-ef-core-queries-with-tagwithcallsite
it is only possible with reflection..

Comment: Leave time for decorating all queries manually. I had idea what you can do here, but extensibility of EF6 is too low. Replacing `IQueryProvider` for EF Core can make it work with stack analysis but not for EF6 (just checked their sources).